# How Do I Go About This Photoshop Bulk Templating

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow, automation, batch-processing

I have a folder with designs that need no further work designwise. They all need the same treatment, to have **width** set to **500**.

Once treated each and every image needs to be put through two generated filters (*added into template frames with shadows et.c*) and then have the area cropped and saved, foldered and indexed with the originally shrunk image being named 00, the first filter design named 01 and the third filter 03.

**What would be effective ways of executing this?**

Comment: Why do you nee dthe way to be most eficient?

Comment: I work for a small firm, time is money, doing this manually takes an estimated 5 minutes per image, that's 6.25 hours for 75 products if I'm not wrong. Anything that would drastically shorten the workload would be highly appreciated. I have some years of PS experience but it's almost exclusively design work, I have no experience in automating.

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual about creating PS actions?

Comment: Are these "filters" actual filters or actions that you have created? That makes a real difference.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor They are picture templates

Comment: Ok, so you're pasting a picture over the final design?

Comment: @Ovaryraptor Yes, that I do

Answer (score 0):

your design folder take only one Imageand  first open as photoshop and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and create a new action>Record, now it depends on design( Use Crop Tool shortcut key <kbd>C</kbd> and top bar, make width 500px and your design size) or use (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Image size) width as 500pixels your chooses), in action panel >stop playing/rocecding.. After this you close the file and don't save it.

Then go to file>scripts>Image processor>select folder to process>select save location>File type, quality 5 or 3 your choose>Preference,Run action>set1>you action name>RUN.

One More Option Here :-
Go to file>scripts>Load Layers>Browse>Select all design>Ok,
After it will open and now crop it shortcut <kbd>C</kbd> and top two bar like arrow right and left there you go type 500 and 500 and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Image size) width as 500pixels x 500pixels > ok

After Select all Layer shortcut key <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then File>Export>Expor layer to file>Browse Where you want to save>Your setting>Run